# Get values from Json to filter array on click

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have this json which i need to convert according to the image below using angular.
I was able to list out the data using `*ngFor` (image attached below), i want to display the categories on click. how can i do that ?

```
{
  "top wear": [
    "shirts",
    "t-shirts",
    "jackets"
  ],
  "bottom wear": [
    "jeans",
    "chinos",
    "shorts"
  ],
  "foot wear": [
    "shoes",
    "sandals",
    "slides"
  ]
}
```

html code

```
<div class="cards">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let list of dataList | keyvalue">
            {{list.key}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<hr>
<div *ngFor="let list of dataList | keyvalue">
    {{list.value}}
</div>
```

**Result i want:**

[image]

**Result i have currently:**

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply store the selected key, with selectedKey being a field in your ts file

```
<div class="cards">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let list of dataList | keyvalue" (click)="setSelectedKey(list.key)">
            {{list.key}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<hr>
<div>{{list[selectedKey]}}</div>
```